# Disable Mini-Map Rotation in Battlefield 3

Tags: battlefield-3

Is there a way to disable the mini-map rotation in Battlefield 3? I would rather North on the map was always facing up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way that I've been able to find to do this, is to press <kbd>N</kbd> twice.

The (extremely big) downside to this, is that it means your map is at minimum zoom level, showing the entire map at once.

Comment: Too bad I can't window it and stick it on a second monitor. But thanks, I never noticed it did this, maybe I can just get used to the N twice with the bigger mode M

Comment: @KyleBrandt I use N twice with M whenever I'm in a vehicle. The only downside is that you lose the ability to see who owns what objectives, and what the ticket count is. The upside is if someone's spotted anywhere on the map, you can track them at all times, and you can see when a vehicle becomes empty anywhere on the map too.

Comment: Also, a lot of us are on maybe 8pm-ish EST on the SE Bf3 server (http://s.tk/bf3) ;-)

Comment: @KyleBrandt Would love to play on there with you guys, but being in Aus, my ping doesn't even show up because it's too high (just get the little dash -ms)